# Inserting Whitespace before and after regex match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to the Python language and regular expressions in Python so I hope someone might be able to give me some advice on the best way to solve this problem.

I am looping through a list of strings and I'm trying to 'split' the strings when a certain regex is encountered (to compensade for user input error).

For example, looking for the C/S pattern,

```
C/S100
```

should become

```
 C/S 100
```

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(C/S)', r' \1 ', string)`

Comment: you dont need regex. `'C/S100'.replace('C/S','C/S ')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` function like below.

```
>>> s = "C/S100"
>>> re.sub(r'(C/S)', r' \1 ', s)
' C/S 100'
```

**Update:**

```
>>> s = "C/S100"
>>> var = "C/S"
>>> re.sub('('+var+')', r' \1 ', s)
' C/S 100'
```

Comment: Using this method could I use a variable rather than C/S because C/S is just one of the strings i will be looking for. For example: s = C/S100 var = C/S re.sub(r'(var)', r' \1 ', s)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "C/S100"
print re.sub(r'(?=(?:C/S))|(?<=(?:C/S))', r' ', s)
```

Output:`C/S 100`

You dont need to cpature at all.Just find the point behind match and after match.